# Is there a way to auto-create a sections Site Settings and propagate when a new site is created?

Tags: localization, sites

My customer will have lots of sections and lots of entries in each, for each site. Over time they will add new language sites.

When a new site is added, there are no sections or entries for it. So we have to then edit each section to set the URL format and template, even though they will be the same for each site.

I would like to make it as easy and quick for the customer to add new sites.

So is there a way I can automatically set these values, enable the site, and propagate entries, for every section (or even certain sections), every time they create a new Site?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Yes it is but only with PHP. Do you search for a solution without custom code?

Comment: Searching for solution with or without code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_SITE` event to create/update the new section settings

```PHP
Event::on(
    Sites::class,
    Sites::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_SITE,
    function (SiteEvent $event) {
        if ($event->isNew) {

            ProjectConfigHelper::ensureAllSitesProcessed();
            $siteId = $event->site->id;

            // array of sections you want to propagate
            $sectionsToActivate = [
                'test',
            ];

            foreach ($sectionsToActivate as $sectionHandle){

                $section = Craft::$app->getSections()->getSectionByHandle($sectionHandle);
                if($section !== null){
                    /** @var \craft\models\Section_SiteSettings[] $siteSettings */
                    $siteSettings = $section->getSiteSettings();

                    // the site you want to clone from
                    $siteSettings[$siteId] = clone $siteSettings[1]; 
                    $siteSettings[$siteId]->id = null;
                    $siteSettings[$siteId]->siteId = $siteId;

                    // eventually you want to change some other settings ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                    //$siteSettings[$siteId]->template = '';
                    //$siteSettings[$siteId]->uriFormat = '';
                    //$siteSettings[$siteId]->hasUrls = '';

                    $section->setSiteSettings($siteSettings);
                   Craft::$app->getSections()->saveSection($section);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Explanation: As soon as you create a new site, you'll loop all sections you want to activate and grab their "main" site settings, copy them and set the `id` to null in order to create a new record

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I need to implement this solution too. Any chance you can provide more info on how you got this working? Presuming you created a custom module. I'm not very experienced with that part of Craft yet.

Comment: @Dr_Codswallop yes you need indeed a custom module for this, but to explain how to do that exactly would be too much for a comment. You could read about the basics here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules